# Bit reduction unary operator in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog, verification, unary-operator, bitwise-or, register-transfer-level

Is there a limit of bit reduction for buses or signals in system verilog?

I want to detect at least a "1" in the node below and I am using an "OR" operator, however, its not working properly in some cases. This is the behavior I am seeing in the simulation:

```
             |000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0010=1
             |000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001=1
             |100_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=0
             |110_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=0
             |111_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=1
```

Is the OR unary bit reduction operator limited to 41 bits? meaning that I cannot reduce a bus/node equal or greater than 42 bits?

Thanks in advance

This is the code:

```
             node detect_ones  = 1; 
             node [`175-1:0] output_data;

             assign detect_ones   =  (|output_data[42:0])
```

Comment: There is a limit, but nowhere near 41 bits. Can you show the code including all declarations?

Comment: thanks  for the replay. I  just edited the original post with the code

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/GQg) showing it working.

However if you miss the 43'b declaration the results are different.

```
|000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0010=1
|000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001=1
|100_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=0
|110_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=0
|111_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=1
```

Should be :

```
|43'b000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0010=1
|43'b000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001=1
|43'b100_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=1
|43'b110_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=1
|43'b111_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000=1
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the experiment. At least it shows me that the expression should work